# How to switch to adjacent tabs in distraction free mode in IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea, navigationbar

I am using Intellij for quite some time. I recently found there is `distraction free mode` in the IDE. The problem is I am not able to switch tabs in distraction free mode. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd> did not work. I already found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> for recent files. I want the answer similar to  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-></kbd>. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Make sure you run the latest IntelliJ IDEA version. In case the issue persists, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the video of the problem and the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I am using IntelliJ Idea 2018.2.3 Ultimate which is the latest version available now.

Comment: Then please follow the second part of my comment.